# Failed to update UIImageView

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, nsurlconnection

I'm trying to stream MJPEG video into my iOS app through a local IP. The connection is established and the stream is a success, I can see the hex values update in my console. However the UIImageView shows only the first frame it received and doesn't update after that. Whats wrong in the code? I even tried refreshing the view with setNeedsDisplay, it didn't help. I know NSURLConnection is deprecated in iOS 9+, this is just to test code so how can this be fixed?

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize recievedData;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    NSURLRequest *theRequest =
    [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.0.15:8090/?action=stream"]];
    NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
    recievedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [recievedData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    NSLog(@"%@",recievedData);

    UIImage *recievedImage = [UIImage imageWithData:recievedData];
    self.streamView.image = recievedImage;
        [self.streamView setNeedsDisplay];


}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

as i see this is video stream and you need to use video player to display content of media.

Comment: Its an image stream not a video stream, its in "MJPEG" format. It just needs to grab images and update it in UIImageView.
MJPEG - In multimedia, Motion JPEG (M-JPEG or MJPEG) is a video compression format in which each video frame or interlaced field of a digital video sequence is compressed separately as a JPEG image.